# Which user account to use within WebDeploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, tfs, windows-server-2012

I have installed WebDeploy on my IIS server to allow publishing of sites via TFS. On configuring web deploy for a particular site, which user account should I use?

Within the [IIS tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy), we are told to use a *non-administrator Windows* user,  but the [ASP.NET tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-%28web-deploy-handler%29) seems to show a generic user.  By default, Web Deploy selects the server administrator, which surely can't be good:

[image: Web deploy user]

Should we create a new account and specify *that* username and password within TFS?
Some blogs suggest doing this and setting the password to *never expire*.  If so, which permissions need setting on which directories for our new user?

I see there is also a **WDeployAdmin** user which has been created during install.  Is this relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general approach is to create a service account that has access to the resources needed to deploy the files to the target machine, including but not limited to

1. access by including deploy account in file / directory permission lists
2. Local administrator to modify / add virtual directories or other IIS settings

Note that the password should be set to never expire.

*Normally the account used is a local admin ( not domain admin ) on the box where the web deploy is taking place. Microsoft attempted to fix web deploy so that not admin users can use web deploy but it does have its own issues.*

http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2011/04/05/announcing-web-deploy-2-0-refresh.aspx

I would normally use an account that is local admin on the target system where the web site is being deployed.

WDeployAdmin would appear to be used for non-admin users to install. I would create a separate service account for deployment process.

Comment: So I should not simply select **WDeployAdmin** from the dialog box?  Moreso, how do I know *what* permissions are needed?  Is it trial and error?  Is seems odd that there are no specifics on this within the tutorials.